# Please delete two chat rooms created by accident

Tags: support, status-completed, chat

This below links are to chat rooms I mistakenly created. They were intended for the MusicFans chat site. Not sure how they ended up in the MP&T chat. (And would be happy to know!)

- https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/133297/answers-to-views-could-you-find-this-melody-starting-with-a4-c5-e5-4-times-a
- https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/133296/answers-to-views-could-you-find-this-melody-starting-with-a4-c5-e5-4-times-an

Comment: I can also move them to this site if that works.

Comment: @Dom Much appreciated. One is enough; they're identical.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bottom one is deleted, top one is moved to music fans. In general, any SE mod can do chat room admin options so there may be a faster path to getting it resolved. Not sure a chat flag is appropriate, but I'll double check on meta SE if there's a known process for this.